# error while running basic code with SimpleScalar

Tags: c, linux, simulator

I am trying to use SimpleScalar to run a very basic code just for testing. this is the code I am running:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    int x = 0;
    for ( x = 0; x < 1000000; x++ ) {


    }
    printf("Hello World \n");


}
```

and these are the lines I used to compile and run the program with simple-sim to a folder named results.

> gcc sstest.c -o sstest
>
> ./sim-safe -redir:sim results/hello.sim.out -redir:prog
>   results/hello.prog.out sstest.

However, the program output is empty and the simulator output gives the following error:

> fatal: bad magic number in executable `sstest' (not an executable)

Is there something I am doing wrong in the process? I would appreciate your help very much. Also I am using Ubuntu as operating system and c as a programming language.

Comment: Just curious - Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: @ryyker yes I did, with your answer. I was waaay off, and didn't even know I had to compile with ssbig-na-sstrix-gcc. It took me a while to get it working and I forgot to accept the answer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  It looked to me like you had some of it, just missing the compiler instruction.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *bad magic number in executable `sstest'*  error message may be an indicator that your binary is not compatible for use with *SimpleScaler*.

The compiler script you show: `gcc sstest.c -o sstest` is for creating an ordinary binary.  There is nothing about the code that should cause a failure to compile, or run as a normal executable, but it was not built using the SimpleScaler utility.

From *[this SimpleScaler tutorial](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&ved=0ahUKEwiwpqjcn9LMAhWFoD4KHULwBzwQFghSMAc&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cse.chalmers.se%2Fedu%2Fyear%2F2009%2Fcourse%2FDAT105%2Fold_project_2008%2FDAT105_Tools.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGZWjLi-gxGawT37VHulYGOq9nQVA&sig2=vvYbQvATAwLa_0Ca9t0Kcg&cad=rja)*:

To create a SimpleScaler binary, in particular a C program using GCC you would use:

```
ssbig-na-sstrix-gcc -g -O -o foo foo.c -lm
```

From the same link, to run the program once it is built, you could use:

```
sim-safe [-sim opts] foo [-program opts]
```

Which appears to follow the form of what you have shown in your post:

```
./sim-safe -redir:sim results/hello.sim.out -redir:prog results/hello.prog.out sstest.
```